# Different behaviours on same link_to helpers - Template is missing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a two link_to helpers in a page, created differently. I need to get my response as .js, not .html. This link_to below just works fine, processing, outputting **Processing by PatientsController#load as JS**, which is the correct behaviour.

```
<%= link_to image_tag(sender.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "wht admintabletrtd1image-none click_load"), patient_load_path(sender.id), :remote => true, :alt => "user"%>
```

However, another link_to helper (see below) in my page does not. When clicked, it outputs **Processing by PatientsController#load as HTML**, and resulting in missing template error.

```
<%= link_to :controller => n.specific.subject[:type].pluralize, :action => :load, :id => n.specific.subject[:id], :remote => true do %> // for the sake of this example, it becomes <%= :controller => 'patients', :action => :load, :id => 4, :remote => true do %>
```

They both output the same link, **patients/4/load**. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try this `<%= link_to ' ', :controller => n.specific.subject[:type].pluralize, :action => :load, :id => n.specific.subject[:id], :remote => true do %>`

Comment: @Pavan It is referencing to the current page. Not working :/

Answer (score 0):

The method signature on the second link is wrong.

> ```
> link_to(body, url, html_options = {})
>   # url is a String; you can use URL helpers like
>   # posts_path
>
> link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
>   # url_options, except :method, is passed to url_for
>
> link_to(options = {}, html_options = {}) do
>   # name
> end
>
> link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
>   # name
> end
> ```
>
> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

In the first link you are passing a literal string as the url. The second uses an older more verbose, non-resource-oriented syntax.

Leaving off the brackets which delimit the url options and the html options (`remote: true` is really just a data attribute) gives the wrong link:

> ```
> link_to "WRONG!", controller: "articles", id: "news", class: "article"
> # => <a href="/articles/index/news?class=article">WRONG!</a>
> ```

The second example should read something like this:

```
link_to({ 
  controller: n.specific.subject[:type].pluralize, 
  action: :load, 
  id: n.specific.subject[:id] 
}, { remote: true }) do # ...
```

But you might want let the rails polymorphic routes helper do the job of figuring out the controller for you:

```
link_to([n.specific, :load], remote: true) do # ...
```

Comment: The odd things is that, both my code and yours generates the correct HTML
`<a data-remote="true" href="/patients/4/load"></a>`. However, your solution did not work either :/

Comment: Could it be a script error somewhere? `link_to` with `remote: true` and `remote: false` should generate the exact same HTML save for the data-remote attribute. Its the jquery_ujs driver the that alters the behavior of the link.

Comment: It seems to me that way too. However I don't have any idea why it would differ in the same page.

Comment: No clues in the browser console?